# Adding list item to DataFrame column if it exists within a range

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to add list items to specified columns within a DataFrame if a list item exists in the specified position.

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Letter', 'Headline 1', 'Headline 2', 'Headline 3', 'Headline 4', 'Headline 5', 'Headline 6'])
data = {'Letter':['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I'm attempting to do so with a series of if statements.  It works if there is a list item in the specified position.  I'm sure that this isn't an ideal way to accomplish what I am looking for.  It also doesn't work if one of the list items is out of range.  Ideally, I would like to insert an empty string if the list item doesn't exist.

```
if list1[0]:
    df['Headline1'] = list1[0]
    
if list1[1]:
    df['Headline2'] = list1[1]
    
if list1[2]:
    df['Headline3'] = list1[2]
    
if list1[3]:
    df['Headline4'] = list1[3]
    
if list1[4]:
    df['Headline5'] = list1[4]
    
if list1[5]:
    df['Headline6'] = list1[5]
```

Desired Output:

```
  Letter Headline1 Headline2 Headline3 Headline4 Headline5 Headline6
0    one     a          b        c          d          e           
1    two     a          b        c          d          e           
2  three     a          b        c          d          e           
3   four     a          b        c          d          e           
4   five     a          b        c          d          e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with dictionary created by `zip`:

```
L = [f'Headline {x+1}' for x in range(list1)]
d = dict(zip(L, list1))
df = pd.DataFrame(data).assign(**d)
print (df)
  Letter Headline 1 Headline 2 Headline 3 Headline 4 Headline 5
0    one          a          b          c          d          e
1    two          a          b          c          d          e
2  three          a          b          c          d          e
3   four          a          b          c          d          e
4   five          a          b          c          d          e
```

---

```
L = ['Headline 1', 'Headline 2', 'Headline 3', 'Headline 4', 'Headline 5', 'Headline 6']
d = dict(zip(L, list1))
df = pd.DataFrame(data).assign(**d)
print (df)
  Letter Headline 1 Headline 2 Headline 3 Headline 4 Headline 5
0    one          a          b          c          d          e
1    two          a          b          c          d          e
2  three          a          b          c          d          e
3   four          a          b          c          d          e
4   five          a          b          c          d          e
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `assign` with unpacking and `dropna`:

```
df.assign(**data).fillna(dict(zip(df.columns[1:], list1))).dropna(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  Letter Headline 1 Headline 2 Headline 3 Headline 4 Headline 5
0    one          a          b          c          d          e
1    two          a          b          c          d          e
2  three          a          b          c          d          e
3   four          a          b          c          d          e
4   five          a          b          c          d          e
```